# EF6 - Handling intensive concurrent insert operations?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have a straightforward scenario interacting with Sql server database - we insert a record into the database table for certain purpose of logging and since the data have been inserted, it shall never be changed. The only point is that this insert operation happens very frequently and concurrently.

We used to insert with a stored procedure and that was working fine. However, we switch to EF6 recently and we found when there are more intensively insertion, the operations more likely end up with an exception:

> Messsage:An exception has been raised that is likely due to a
>   transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database
>   consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.
>
> StackTrace:   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions
>   options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()

The code segment is like this:

```
using (MyRepository repo = new MyRepository(new MyDbContext()))
{
    var logData = new LogData()
    {
        //Initialize the object
    };
    //Repo.Add adds the object into the context set
    repo.Add(logData);
    //Repo.Complete calls SaveChanges of the context
    repo.Complete();
}
```

We have tried disabling `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`, but it didn't improve the case.
Since those insertions take place in independent threads, there is less possibility to organize the requests in an iterate loop.

I would like to ask if there is a smarter way to tweak this?

Comment: Does your `MyReository` class handle disposing of the `MyDbContext` automatically?  If not, you have a pretty big potential problem if this code gets executes a lot.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes, it implements the IDispose and closes the DbContext in the Dispose method.

Comment: You might be able to use the producer / consumer pattern to handle writing the log data in batches, if you don't mind a bit of a delay before the data actually gets inserted. Add the log data to a queue that gets dumped in batches every `x` items or every `y` minutes.

Comment: @BradleyUffner We actually do need the insert operations happen in time due to it reflects the exact time what is happening. So that delay is less tolerant in our scenario.

Comment: Can't you just include a timestamp in your log (when it was logged, not when it was saved in the db)?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yes, we do. So the best practice still should be batch insert operation, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily best practice, but with the EF overhead it might be a good option. If this is your only bottleneck you could of course also write directly into the db instead of using EF for the log table.

Answer (score 0):

As exception text suggests, you should implement `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy`. Just place this `class` to same assembly, where your `context` is declared:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => SuspendExecutionStrategy
          ? (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy()
          : new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
    }

    public static bool SuspendExecutionStrategy
    {
        get { 
           return (bool?)CallContext.LogicalGetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy") ?? false; 
        }
        set { CallContext.LogicalSetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy", value); }
    }
}
```

Your exception could be caused, for example, by network problems or another ones, not related with database, it's probability grows at case of very intensive insert operation rate. So, presented configuration will retry failed request by itself without your interaction. You can read more [here](https://romiller.com/2013/08/19/ef6-suspendable-execution-strategy/).